# Copying content of array to resized array in C++

Tags: c++, arrays, realloc

I've searched through many topics here, but they didn't seem to answer me exactly.

I'm trying to do some dynamic reallocation od arrays in C++. I can't use anything from STL libraries as I need to use this in homework where STL (vectors,...) is explicitly forbidden.

So far, I've tried to elaborate with code like this:

```
int * items = new int[3]; //my original array I'm about to resize
int * temp = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) temp[i] = items[i];

delete [] items;   //is this necessary to delete?
items = new int [10];
for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) items[i] = temp[i];
delete [] temp;
```

This seem to work, but what bothers me is the excessive number of iterations. Can't this be done anyhow smarter? Obviously, I'm working with much larger arrays than this. Unfortunately, I **have to** work with arrays though.

**edit:** When I try to do `items = temp;` instead of

`for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) items[i] = temp[i];` and try to `std::cout` all my elements, I end up with losing first two elements, but ***valgrind*** prints them correctly.

Comment: When this is for homework, the smarter thing would be to encapsulate it, i.e. rewrite the parts of std::vector that you need... depending on what your definition of "stl" is, you might be able to use things like std::copy to encapsulate the copying process.

Comment: Remember that pointers are normal variables, and therefore can be reassigned...

Comment: Been a while since I touched C++ but, do you need to copy items[] to temp[] then from temp[] abck to items[]? Can't you just create a new pointer to items[] - `int *temp = items;` then recreate items - `items = new int[10]`. Do your copy from `temp` to `items` - perhaps look at the `memcopy` function or the `std::copy` function to do this most efficiently. Then delete `temp`.

Comment: @wmorrison365 `int * temp = items;` makes my program crash.

Comment: @wmorrison365 Thank you very much! `copy (temp, temp+10, items);` works like a charm!

Comment: @Saraph... curious, what's the crash reporting? As I say I'm out of date but that just sounds odd. Have you made progress, anyway?

Comment: @wmorrison365 Yes, I've made that work already. For the error thing, it was just that classic over-100-lines junk. I can't really read through it.

Answer (score 5):

Yes, the first `delete[]` is necessary. Without it, you'd be leaking memory.

As to the code that comes after that first `delete[]`, all of it can be replaced with:

```
items = temp;
```

This would make `items` point to the ten-element array you've just populated:

```
int * items = new int[3]; //my original array I'm about to resize
int * temp = new int[10];
for (int i = 0; i < 3; i++) temp[i] = items[i];
delete [] items;   //delete the original array before overwriting the pointer
items = temp;
```

Finally, don't forget to `delete[] items;` when you are done with the array.

Comment: Weird, I had some errors with `items = temp;`. I somehow lost first two elements.

Comment: @NPE didn't you mixed up the sequence? better write down the code than describe it

Answer (score 0):

The containers of the `STL` were made to ease work like this. It is tedious, but there is not much of a choice, when you need to use `C`-arrays.

The deletion of

```
delete [] items;
```

is necessary, as when you abandon the reference to the array, which you would do with assigning a new reference in

```
items = new int [10];
```

will cause a memory leak, so this is necessary.